# Twitter bootstrap show modal from by another modal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve the effect on bootstrap that when new modal is opening the previous one will be hidden. I couldn't find good solution to this problem.

```
 $('.show_second_modal').click(function (){
        $('#first_modal').modal('hide').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (){
            $('#second_modal').modal('show');
        });        
   });
```

Here are my attempts: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kohnxe2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please verify your markup again: your `form` closing tags are placed between div tags like this:

```
<form ...>
    ...
    <div>
        ...
        </form>
    </div>
...
```

I've updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5kohnxe2/1/), now looks ok.

Comment: I did not notice this :) Thank you so much. I had no idea that this may be the reason.

Comment: You're welcome! You also may want to check @fernandopasik's answer, which doesn't involve javascript at all and seems pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

I've removed the javascript and updated the targets for the modals.

Also when you close the register it returns to the login

http://jsfiddle.net/5kohnxe2/4/

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register_modal">Anuluj</button>
```